# How to loop multiple nested loop in one table in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

I have referral commission details and different levels of referral users I need to show that in the table with there are levels. Here I did coded but I'm not satisfied with the logic please let me know the logic is correct or wrong you see the below images for reference.

What i'm looking for

[image]

Here my table

[image: Table image]

What i did so far

Controller

```
  public function inDirectCommission()
  {

    $user =  User::where('id', 1)->first();
    $user_id = $user->id;

    $direct_commissions = Referral::where('parent_id', $user_id)->get();

    foreach ($direct_commissions as $row) {
      $second_level = Referral::where('parent_id', $row->user_id)->get();
      foreach ($second_level as $row) {
        $third_level = Referral::where('parent_id', $row->user_id)->get();
        foreach ($third_level as $row) {
          $forth_level = Referral::where('parent_id', $row->user_id)->get();
          foreach ($forth_level as $row) {
            $fifth_level = Referral::where('parent_id', $row->user_id)->get();
            foreach ($fifth_level as $row) {
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }

    return view('site.user.dashboard.commission.in_direct_commission', compact('second_level', 'third_level', 'forth_level', 'fifth_level'));
  }
```

Blade

```
<table id="example1"
   class="table table-bordered table-striped dataTable dtr-inline direct-table"
   role="grid" aria-describedby="example1_info">
   <thead>
      <tr>
         <th>Date</th>
         <th>Referal</th>
         <th>Level</th>
         <th>Amount</th>
      </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
      @foreach ($second_level as $row)
      <tr>
         <td>{{ $row->created_at }}</td>
         <td>{{ $row->user->name }}</td>
         <td>2<sup>nd</sup> Level</td>
         <td>4000</td>
      </tr>
      @endforeach
      @foreach ($third_level as $row)
      <tr>
         <td>{{ $row->created_at }}</td>
         <td>{{ $row->user->name }}</td>
         <td>3rd<sup>rd</sup> Level</td>
         <td>3000</td>
      </tr>
      @endforeach
      @foreach ($forth_level as $row)
      <tr>
         <td>{{ $row->created_at }}</td>
         <td>{{ $row->user->name }}</td>
         <td>4<sup>th</sup> Level</td>
         <td>2000</td>
      </tr>
      @endforeach
      @foreach ($fifth_level as $row)
      <tr>
         <td>{{ $row->created_at }}</td>
         <td>{{ $row->user->name }}</td>
         <td>5<sup>th</sup> Level</td>
         <td>1000</td>
      </tr>
      @endforeach
   </tbody>
</table>
```

dd of second level user

[image: Collection dump]

Comment: How many levels do you have. When you have multiple levels is going to be messy if you have too many levels of anything. The traversal is going to be a pain. My suggestion is to save the referral chain as a column with the user in the database. Then you can use the chain column to capture what ever you want.

Comment: One user have a 5 level referral user 1st level user call as direct referral that referral user details showing in different table. In this table we are staring with level 2 and end with level 5 here i needs to get level 2-5 referral users. Can you please explain more how can do this?

Comment: I've posted an answer. You would have to adjust the concept as per your needs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**IMPORTANT**: as per my comments under the question, this answer is to emphasize the idea only. Code samples and concepts might need to be adjusted to match your needs.

Assume there are users A,B,C,D,E and F and each has ids 1,2,3,4,5 and 6 respectively.

Also let's assume 'A' was a directly registered user. And:

- A refers B to the website
- B refers C to the website
- C refers D to the website
- D refers E to the website, and
- E refers F to the website

With each user record, you can store their referral chain (`ref_chain`) in the database. At the time of user registration you can do this.

```
$a->ref_chain = null; // because he hasn't been referred by anyone
$b->ref_chain = '1';  // B (id = 2) is a direct referral of A (id = 1)
$c->ref_chain = '2-1'; // C (id = 3) is a direct referral of B (id = 2)
$d->ref_chain = '3-2-1'; // D (id = 4) is a direct referral of C (id = 3)

// similarly

$e->ref_chain = '4-3-2-1';
$f->ref_chain = '5-4-3-2-1';
```

Here, what you do is, at the time of registration you get the referring user's `ref_chain` and attach referring user's id to to the beginning of the string with a hyphen. For an example if we consider the time of C's registration:

```
$referringUser = $b;
$c->ref_chain = $b->id.'-'.$b->ref_chain;
```

Now consider the scenario where you want to get the referrals of C.

What you have to do is search in the `ref_chain` column in the database using the SQL `like` keyword;

```
$referralsOfC = User::where('ref_chain','like',$c->id.'-%')
                      ->orWhere('ref_chain','like','%-'.$c->id.'-%')
                      ->orWhere('ref_chain','like','%-'.$c->id)
                      ->orWhere('ref_chain',"$c->id")
                      ->get();
```

After that, you can loop through the collection and display the result as you please. Depending on the position of C's id in the `ref_chain` attribute you can recognize which level the referral is in.

This way you can drastically reduce the number of database queries and traversal.

Hope you can understand.

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer! But how can get all the referrals levels? And show in the table? like 1st image

Comment: You may have to come up with something. I was thinking using php explode function `explode('-',$user->ref_chain)` and php `array_search`

Comment: Can you please explain more if you don't mind.

Comment: ```$level = explode('-', $row->ref_chain); $key = array_search(1, $level);``` like this?

Comment: @Thush yeah. assuming 1 is the user's id. If $key is 0 that means the referral is a direct referral. $key = 1 -> next level and so on and so forth

Comment: Assume if direct user getting commission  4000 and 2nd level greeting commission  3000 in this how can i get total do you have any idea? currently commission amount is static.

Comment: I think you should be able to calculate the value at the time of the registration. And saving somewhere of course.

Comment: When F registering needs to get all parent data's like A,B,C,D,E and calculate value and store into somewhere?

Comment: Yeah. I'm sure you'd be able to figure out something that works for you. Even if it's going to be costly on resources side, since registration is a one time thing, I think it'd not be that much of a issue.